# I would like to fax from my Mac running High Sierra

Tags: macos, fax

I need to fax a couple of pages from my Mac. My printer doesn't seem to support faxing. I found one online site that will fax from a mac but they wanted a monthly subscription starting at $12.95 a month. Is there another way to fax without going somewhere that will fax for me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to upgrade your printer, buy/borrow a fax machine or pay for an online service, then the only remaining options are:

1. print the pages and take them somewhere to fax for you
2. find an online fax service with a free trial period
3. use a fax modem<sup>1</sup> if you happen to have an old one laying around

If this is a once off I would just print the pages and take them to your workplace or a local post office (or anywhere that has a fax machine) and ask if they can fax them for you. Even if they charge a couple of dollars, this is probably the best option.

Otherwise you should be able to find an online fax service with a free trial period. I just did a quick search and found that https://en.efax.com offers a 30 day trial period. No doubt you will need to provide payment details as part of the registration, but typically with these types of services you can just contact them and cancel your account prior to the trial period ending.

<sup>1.</sup> macOS Sierra doesn't natively support fax modems but there used to be a range of 3rd party fax programs, so you could use one of these. Or maybe just use another computer or install El Capitan on a virtual machine to do this. Or, if you happen to have Windows installed (either via Bootcamp or a virtual machine), that should do the trick too.

Comment: Thanks. I saw efax but the page said Windows to Windows only. No Macs. Has that changed or did you check? I'll check again.

Comment: I didn't specifically check in terms of macOS support, but typically these services offer a digital fax service that allows you to just send an email which then gets converted to a fax and sent to the relevant fax number. This is platform independent - as long as you can send an email it'll work. However, I did note on the site there were iOS and Android apps available, so I assumed this would meet your needs. :) If not, and you can't find one that does, let me know.

Comment: thanks very much. I probably won't get that unless I'm forced to. Many of these free trial packages add the free trial along with a monthly subscription.  Their price is too high for a single fax, but I may try it anyway.

Comment: I went ahead and signed up for a free trial from efax. I went thru the registration process and then tried faxing my info.  The fax started according to the window and ran for about 5 minutes. I then got a message saying 'General System Error' and it stopped. I've tried about 10-15 times varying my input a little but I always get the same error message. I'll try the mobile app they offer. I'll let you know the results.  Thanks.

Comment: Well no luck with the mobile app. The interface is very difficult to use and it eventually takes you to what looks like the same page on the efax site for sending faxes.  The print was very small. I didn't try it because I could hardly see it and it appeared exactly like the page that i described for the desktop version.  I think the mobile app is just a link to the efax web site.